# autofac/c# : A generic factory for a specific base class?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, factory, autofac

Is it possible for autofac to create a generic factory that can only resolve types of a specific base class?

I'm currently seeing how feasible it is to retrofit a 'brownfield' c# project to use autofac.  The project requires creating a tree of components of differing types but of the same base class. These components require authentication and database services (among other things) so it makes it hard to just have empty constructors.

So the factory would be so a user can create objects deriving a base class, use autofac to scan for these classes, and provide a factory for them.  I thought it might make it easier to build component object trees if you didn't have to provide factories for each class.

As an aside, or is this a sign of bad design?  Should the components and the tree do as little as possible and we pass this tree to other services to provide processing and rendering?

Something like (where ? is the mystery factory)

```
public MyBase { 
    public Add(MyBase x) {..}
}

public DerivedA: MyBase {}

public DerivedB : MyBase {}

public DerivedC : DerivedA {}

public SomethingElse
{
     private ? _myBaseFact;

     public SomethingElse(? myBaseFact) { 
            _myBaseFact = myBaseFact;
     }

     public BuildComponentTree() {
        DerivedA a = _myBaseFact<DerivedA>();
        DerivedB b = _myBaseFact<DerivedB>();
        DerivedC c = _myBaseFact<DerivedC>();
        a.Add(b);
        b.Add(c);
     }
}
```

edit: I have been asked for a more concrete example, which is fair :) There are framework components and I wanted to allow for the developers to create their own components without having to register with autofac.  Having a factory class would mean that the developer would have to add their custom components to this factory right?  Please excuse the example, this is similar to how the framework works when I encountered it.

```
FwComponent {
    public FwComponent (DataProvider, AuthManager, OtherModule)
    public Add(FwComponent x);
    public Setup();
    public Process();
    public Render();
}

Page : FwComponent {
    public Page(DataProvider, AuthManager, OtherModule): base(..)
    public string Title;
    ...
}

Input: FwComponent {
    public Input(DataProvider, AuthManager, OtherModule): base(..)
    public string Name;
    public int length;
    ...
}

Button: FwComponent {
    public Button(DataProvider, AuthManager, OtherModule): base(..)
    public string Name;
    ...
}

----

MyCustomButton : Button {
     public MyCustomButton(DataProvider, AuthManager, OtherModule): base(..)
}

MyPersonalPage : FwComponent {

    IContext _container;

    public MyPersonalPage(DataProvider, AuthManager, OtherModule, IContext container): base(..)

    public Setup() {
         var input = _container.Resolve<Input>();
         input.Name = 'xxx';
         input.length = 10;
         Add(input);

         var butt = _container.Resolve<MyCustomButton>();
         butt.name = "xxx";
         Add(butt);    
    }

    public Process() {
        DataProvider.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code sample you gave, you seem to request for a specific type using `_myBaseFact<DerivedA>()` and `_myBaseFact<DerivedB>()`. It's hard to see what you are trying to accomplish, but this seems like a code smell to me, because you still have a dependency on the concrete types.

As I see it you have two choices: Either you inject a factory and abstract away the derived types, -or- you directly inject the derived types into the constructor. Using a factory is useful in two scenario's:

1: You have some sort of (not type based) argument that allows the factory to identify the returned type, as shown in the following example:

```
public class MyBaseFactory : IMyBaseFactory
{
    public MyBase CreateMyBase(IUserContext user)
    {
        // Create a MyBase based on a user object.
    }
}
```

2: Your factory has multiple factory methods:

```
public class MyBaseFactory : IMyBaseFactory
{
    private Autofac.IContainer container;

    public MyBase CreateMyBaseForScenarioA()
    {
        return container.Resolve<DerivedA>();
    }

    public MyBase CreateMyBaseForScenarioB()
    {
        return container.Resolve<DerivedB>();
    }
}
```

Note that both factory methods return a `MyBase` and never the specific type. The whole idea about polymorphism is that you shouldn't care about the concrete type.

IMO it doesn't matter whether Autofac could create a factory for you or not. You shouldn't rely on framework specific constructs like that, but depend on good application design. If you go for the factory approach, define an interface for that factory and inject an instance based on that interface. This makes the design very clean and it communicates it's intend very nicely.

Comment: I guess I want to allow people to create and instantiant their own subclasses without having to add to a special MyBaseFactory.  I was hoping to utilise a generic factory method and autofac's assembly scanning. It will probably be the case that they'll want to access the subclass directly and not have to cast the base.

Comment: I guess I'm after a way to inject an IContext that only allows resolving base class and its sub classes. I know that doesn't sound like the right way to go about it though.

Comment: @Nick Sonneveld: It sounds like you are very confused as to how polymorphism works, what the purpose of the factory pattern is, and what the point of dependency injection is. Basically, you are abusing AutoFac... this is not what it is meant for.

Comment: @Nick: Perhaps, if you try to explain what you are actually trying to do here, we are able to give you some tips. If possible, update your answer with a more concrete example. What is `MyBase` actually represent? What do the derived types do? What is the function of `SomethingElse` and what does it do with `MyBase` and the derived types?

Comment: Steady on Domenic, I am aware this is possibly a misuse of AutoFac, I was just wondering if it was possible.  I am working with a project where they have components with default constructors, pulling in dependencies from a singleton. It's a bit of a mess at the moment.

Comment: Steven: I'll see what I can come up with. I was trying to leave it a bit abstract.

Comment: Actually, this article looks very similar to what I want to try http://peterspattern.com/generate-generic-factories-with-autofac/ Might have a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: @Nick: After reading your update, it is clear that you're not dealing with services here, but with UI controls. I completely agree with Domenic's answer, and my still stick with my answer: Either define and inject a `IFwComponentFactory` that contains the knowledge of creating concrete components, or new up those UI components directly, if appropriate. Do not abuse Autofac for this. This will only get awkward.

Comment: Thanks Steven, I've been trying to find a way of doing this and creating the least pain for our developers while still providing the benefits of dependency injection.  What would you say is the best way to allow developers to add their own components without modifying IfwComponentFactory? Just override that interface and add their own methods?  I suppose if they're writing code for a class that is aware of their own custom components, can can write code aware of a factory sub-class/interface.

Comment: @Nick: It depends on the structure of your team and your application, so that's hard to say. However, my gut feeling is either change the interface to add new factory methods as they appear, or define new focussed factories along the way. To be productive, I can even imagine starting with new factories and merge them into the `IFwComponentFactory` later on.

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my comment on Steven's answer, your question seems to be predicated on a misunderstanding of the purpose of the factory pattern and of polymorphism. I'll leave those to his answer, but let's get to your misunderstanding of dependency injection...

1) **Dependency injection is meant for services, not entities**

It's not clear what your components and tree are, but I am guessing they are entities in your domain, not services that do processing on them. Dependency injection is for the injection of services (in the most general sense) into other services or glue layers. Examples include injecting a repository into a MVC controller, or a Twitter posting web service into a viewmodel, or a product factory into a product-manipulation service.

2) **Dependency injection and the frameworks thereof have nothing to do with the factory pattern**

Although it is named *AutoFac*, it is not some kind of *auto*matic *fac*tory generator, any more than Unity is a way of unifying all your classes into one or Castle Windsor is a... well... I have no idea. The only connection these two concepts might have is if a factory is one of the aforementioned services you inject.

3) **Dependency injection depends on good design**

That is, you must be using proper object-oriented considerations, like using a constructor to, well, construct a class. Although I suspect the components in your tree are entities (as discussed above), if they were services then an `Add` method would be contrary to these design principles: if a class needs an instance of `MyBase`, it should take that as a constructor parameter, with an appropriate guard clause to throw an exception if this invariant is not met. Similarly, the `SomethingElse` apparently needs a tree of components, which can be specified by the root node: well, then it should take that root node as a constructor parameter.

---

In other words, a dependency-injection friendly version of a tree-like situation would end up looking something like

```
interface INotificationService { }
class TwitterNotificationService : INotificationService { }
class FacebookNotificationService : INotificationService { }
class CompositeNotificationService : INotificationService
{
    public CompositeNotificationService(IEnumerable<NotificationService> services) { }
    // implement composite pattern
}

class NotificationController : Controller
{
    public NotificationController(INotificationService service)
    {
        if (service === null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("service");
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Later, if you were using poor-man's DI, you would do something like

```
var controller = new NotificationController(
        new CompositeNotificationService(new []
        {
            new TwitterNotificationService(),
            new FacebookNotificationService()
        }));
```

The purpose of a DI framework is simply to move the boilerplate construction code such as this into one central location in your application (the *composition root*), effectively removing service construction as a concern from your application and turning it into a configuration detail. But your application needs to be DI-friendly, which really just means conforming to basic OO principles like the use of constructors, for DI to work.

Comment: I wasn't aware that DI was only for connecting services together and not supplying services to entities as well. I guess I was confused by the fact that autofac (and other DI frameworks) allow automatic creation of factories like autofac's delegate factories.

Comment: Great answer! One fat + for that.

Comment: 1) Not trying to inject entities/ui components but services into these entities. I am currently working with a design where these classes are pulling in dependencies from a singleton. It will be difficult to rewrite.
2) I do realise that dependency injection and the factory pattern are unrelated. (thank you for the patronising explanation of autofac's name) I was hoping to leverage autofac's delegate factory feature to create a factory for me.
3) I haven't had a say in the project's initial design. There are existing ui components with a complicated inheritance tree.

Comment: Again, I reiterate that AutoFac in specific and dependency injection frameworks in general are not the right tool for retrofitting a poorly-designed legacy application that contains such antipatterns as e.g. services injected into entities or lack of guaranteed invariants.